# Unable to connect to database (No suitable driver found)

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, windowbuilder

My connection code:

```
try {           
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:myDB.sqlite");
  PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("insert into hell(username,pssword) " +
"values ('"+tfUname.getText()+"','"+tfUpass.getText()+"')");

  pstm.close();
  con.close();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congrats, you have been registered succesfully");
  RegisterWindow rw = new RegisterWindow();
  rw.setVisible(false);
  pack();
  dispose();
} catch(SQLException ex) {
  setTitle(ex.toString());
}
```

This is just a window to insert a user name and password into the database. When I click the button following exception appears:

```
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C\\LoginJava2\\myDB.sqlite"
```

I found an example of how to connect to an SQLite database in Java which works well. I'm doing this in WindowBuilder (Eclipse), using the same driver from the example. I've tried different drivers but that message still appears.

Comment: [See here JDBC PreparedStatement Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)

Comment: [JDBC + SQLite: DriveManager does not load needed driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637389/jdbc-sqlite-drivemanager-does-not-load-needed-driver)

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid url.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your classpath is missing the jar(s) that contain the sqlite classes and driver. You need something like [sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/) or your applicable version.

If you are sure the jar is there, try adding this line of code before you create a connection:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

Comment: it doesn't work with sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar... and if I add the line "Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");" appears an error in that line with this message: "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: @Fenrir86 simply surround it with a try{  .......}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){ ....}

Comment: And make sure you have the sqlite-jdbc-xxxxxxx.jar file in WEB-INF/lib/ if you are running a server like openshift

Comment: It's curious that in my application, which I built as a Macintosh application bundle, I didn't need this line. But I did need it for the executable jar file used by other platforms. I don't know why, but it's good to know the behavior difference between the two platforms.

Comment: i had the same issue  it was relatedt o  sqlite-jbdc-3.7.2 i have switched to "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11" ( using gradle) and it works fine

Comment: this answer really healped me, i put the `sqlite-jdbc-xxx.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib/` and got the exception. but what does `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` do, why does it solve the problem. can anyone explain...

Answer (score 17):

I got the same problem.
I used maven and added dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.1
        </version>
    </dependency>
```

It could be compiled and  I got:

No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:xx.db

I Checked the classpath and I was sure sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar was there.
I guess that for some reason, the Class was not loaded, I don't know why.
so I added

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

at the beginning of my code. It worked!

And ,I delete the line above. It still works! I cleaned the project and rebuild it, no more Class.forName() is needed!!!  I still Don't know why. But the problem is solved. I think  Class.forName() can be used for diagnose if the class you need is in the classpath.

Comment: for me the problem appears again when removing `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")`

Comment: I had the dependency but still saw the error. Resolved after updating the version to 3.30.1.

Answer (score 6):

Also check your database connection string references an existing database.

In the case you:

- Added the sqlite jar library to lib folder under your project, reference to it in the project build path.
- Added Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC") statement.

If the error message "No suit driver" still appears, it's most likely **caused by your incorrect database path**.   Check that path exists.

A properly formatted connection string referencing an existing db file:

Windows

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\db\\my-db.sqlite").
```

Linux

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/your/somepath/my-db.sqlite").
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Maven and want to build an executable jar, you could decide to import the content of the sqlite jar into your own produced jar:

```
<plugins>
  <!-- any other plugins -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>MyPackage.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You will not have to add specific classpath or implicit usage as proposed in the others answers.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the link of central repository from where you can download latest driver files.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/

Make sure that you download **sqlite-jdbc-version.jar** file and not other files.
Hope this might help

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues using a simple gradle configuration as follows

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.2.0'

    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.23.1'

}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'rewards.simulator.MainSimulator'

    }
}
```

I later found that gradle build was creating a jar which was not including any external dependencies. Following configuration is to be used to include all your dependent libraries in the resulting jar file, along with your source files, to create a fat-jar:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.2.0'

    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.23.1'

}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'rewards.simulator.MainSimulator'

    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem of version 3.7.2 try to install 3.21.0 it